# drop-down list is hidden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

html code using bootstrap:

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label id="lbl_dataset">Select Number</label>
         <select class="selectpicker">
           <option>1</option>
           <option>2</option>
           <option>3</option>
           <option>4</option>
           <option selected="selected">5</option>
           <option>6</option>
         </select>
       </div>
       </div>
```

the issue here is that drop-down is hidden, and it only becomes visible after refreshing the page more than once.

while debugging, found that drop-down is disappeared because of this css code

> select.bs-select-hidden, select.selectpicker {
>       display: none !important; }

tried so many times to override bootstrap css but it didn't work.

any idea on how to override bootstrap css ?

Comment: I think you can use inline CSS for doing drop-down visible.

Comment: Read on css specificity. You need higher CSS specificity value & an !important to override it.

Comment: if you use bootstrap CDN then it's may be not possible to overwrite it. add bootstrap locally and then try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using bootstrap through a CDN: In Chrome dev tools, inspect the picker, find the display:none line. Right of the codeline it says which file it is located in. And with that information you can remove the line manually instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with loading bootstrap-select.js

"select" element should be hidden. When "bootstrap-select" loads it hides "select"  and creates new div with all list items.

bootstrap-select.css - hides "select" (among other things)

bootstrap-select.js - creates new HTML elements (such as new dropdown div)